# How to build a ubuntu distro with only the most basic feature

Tags: ubuntu-11.04

As the title says, I want to build a stripped down ubuntu install that only has the most basic
features, I appreciate all help on the subject.

Comment: stackoverflow is for programming questions. Ubuntu linux distro packaging is off topic. Please read the FAQ.

Comment: why do you want such a distro?

Comment: Aditya, thanks for your kind response. I just want to strip out what I don't need in order to reduce overhead.

Comment: You might get a better answer if you ask this on serverfault

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your help. unlike others who give programmers like us a bad name.

Comment: You really need to be a lot more specific.

Answer (score 3):

You'd presumably want to start with installing [ubuntu minimal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) and install the packages you need on top of that. You can then convert the install to a livecd with tools like [remastersys](http://www.geekconnection.org/remastersys/)